# Can't catch null_value_not_allowed exception in postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I was wondering if I am missing something obvious here. I have a function that defines a table name and then goes to query that table in an execute clause. However if there are no data in the main table (one_min, fifteen_min etc) I get back a null_value_not_allowed exception with code 22004. When I try a handler around the exception, it seems to completely by pass it and still die. I tried wrapping the bigger if condition around out with still no luck.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loadresults(force_update boolean)
  RETURNS date AS
$BODY$

declare 
inter int;
startdate date;
table_name varchar(50);

BEGIN

select 1440 / avg(array_length(intervals,1))::int into inter from temptable;

Case inter
    when 1 then 
    table_name := 'one_min';
    when 15 then 
    table_name := 'fifteen_mins';
    when 30 then 
    table_name := 'half_hour';
    when 60 then 
    table_name := 'one_hour';
    else 
       raise EXCEPTION 'I do not recognise the interval %', inter ;
end case;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED ;


if force_update is true then 
    select min(sday) into startdate from temptable ;
else
    begin
        execute ' select max(sday) from ' || table_name
             || ' where (orgid,householdid) in
                 (select orgid, householdid from temptable limit 1 )'
        into startdate ;
    EXCEPTION when null_value_not_allowed then 
        select min(sday) into startdate from temptable; 
    end;
end if;
return startdate;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Given that all the tables exist and work fine - the function carries on to load the data - and it works fine when the force_flag is true.
When the force_update flag is false and there are no data in the one_min table, I get this error back:

```
ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
SQL state: 22004
Context: PL/pgSQL function loadresults(boolean) line 39 at EXECUTE statement
```

This points to the execute statement where the query will not return any values.
Any ideas why that might happen? I'd rather keep the error handling within Postgres rather than my remaining code.

**Update** 
I have now updated the query in the execute clause with this one:

```
execute ' select coalesce(res, tem) from ' ||
 ' (select max(sday) as res from ' || table_name  || ' 
where (orgid,householdid) in (select orgid, householdid from temptable limit 1 )) t1, 
(select min(sday) as tem from temptable) m ' into startdate ;
```

This seems to do the trick as the exception is not raised. I would still like to understand why the exception can't be caught.

Comment: `When the force_update flag is true and there are no data in the one_min table, I get this error back:` How is this possible? The `one_min` is not even touched, the `else` branch is never visited, `EXECUTE` is never executed. There must be some kind of misunderstanding ...

Comment: @JustKim the pl/pgsql variant has `into` clause http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html

Comment: Yeah, I just edited another typo, apologies, I meant the other way around. True works fine where as false dies.

Answer (score 3):

Weird, but it seems, there is two [`null_value_not_allowed`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html) exceptions (`22004` and `39004`).

Try to catch it by their sqlstate, like:

```
BEGIN
    -- ...
EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE '22004' THEN
    -- ...
END;
```

Or, you can achieve the same results, with an additional condition:

```
IF force_update OR table_name IS NULL THEN
    SELECT min(sday) INTO startdate FROM temptable;
ELSE
    EXECUTE 'select max(sday) from '
         || table_name
         || ' where (orgid,householdid) in (select orgid, householdid from temptable limit 1 )'
       INTO startdate;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks pozs, I'll try the first. I tried to return table name before it goes that far in the code but it returns with the correct table name...I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: No luck. with this piece of code, I can see the table name but still the 22004 error comes up. begin 
 raise notice '%', table_name;
 execute ' select max(sday) from ' || table_name || ' where (orgid,householdid) in (select orgid, householdid from temptable limit 1 )' into startdate ;
    EXCEPTION when SQLSTATE '22004' then
 select min(sday) into startdate from temptable; 
    end;

Comment: The error message & code still the same: `query string argument of EXECUTE is null` & `22004`? Pls update your question, to point which line causes the exception (which is near the `Context`)

Comment: In the post I say that with the new query the exception is not being raised. Having null return from old query still returns the exception.